# Return a Json Response from a Controller in Symfony

Tags: php, json, symfony

I am trying return a JSON response from a controller in Symfony 3.4

This is my controller:

```
/**
     * @Route("/message/board/post", name = "message_post")
     * @Method("POST")
     */
    public function postMeg(Request $request)
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $message = new message($request->request->get("txtName"));
        $message->setMes($request->request->get("txtMes"));
        $entityManager->persist($message);
        $entityManager->flush();
        return new JsonResponse(['result' => 'ok', 'ret' => array($entityManager)]);
    }
```

But I get 
**{"result":"ok","ret":[{}]}**
 as Response in the browser

I hope it can show like
 **['result' => 'ok',
'ret' => txtName, txtMes ]**

Comment: That doesn't sound unreasonable to me. What kind of response were you expecting? Could you [edit] to include what you'd like this code to do?

Comment: Try changing `array($entityManager)` to `array($message)`. Also consider using shorthand notation for your arrays; they've been supported since 5.4.

Comment: @maiorano84 I try this `return new JsonResponse(['result' => 'ok', 'ret' => array($message)]);` but sttill show **{"result":"ok","ret":[{}]}**

Comment: @Lai That's odd. That means your `$message` variable likely isn't initialized properly. Double check your class names and make sure your `Message` entity is referenced properly. You can try debugging further by adding `dd([$message, $entityManager])` right before your return and viewing your output. If you have null or empty objects in either of those, then that's your problem.

Comment: Do you have serializer groups (@groups) in your Message entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `$message` instead of `$entityManager` as mentioned in the comments but passing the entity to `new JsonResponse()` will only include `public` properties from the message entity and they are usually all `private`. 
There are many ways to do this, but the easiest is just to insert exactly what you want with the entity's getters:

```
return new JsonResponse([
  'result' => 'ok',
  'ret' => [
    'txtName' => $message->getTxtName(),
    'txtMes ' => $message->getTxtMes(),

  ],
]);
```